# Nuxt - Custom icon-font not served from _nuxt folder

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, webpack-4, mini-css-extract-plugin

I have successfully used the [webfonts-loader](https://github.com/jeerbl/webfonts-loader) package to generate a font and class-definitions for icons, but it isn't served by my nuxt dev server. There is a styletag in my head with:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "TopLoggerIcons";
  src: url("/myfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("/myfont.woff2") format("woff2");
}
```

But the requested `http://localhost:3010/myfont.woff2` gives a 404. I had this working in the nuxt version before 2.0 (and before webpack 4), where the file is served from `http://localhost:3010/_nuxt/myfont.woff2`. The font is currently also served from there, but the path in the font-face declaration is wrong. I'm wondering what has changed here removing the (required?) `_nuxt` part in the path.

In my `nuxt.config.js` file I have:

```
build: {
  extend(config, ctx) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /plugins\/icons\.js$/,
      use: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader', 'webfonts-loader'],
    })
  },
}
```

Now according to the example on the webfonts-loader lib I need to use the `MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader` instead of the `vue-style-loader`, but that doesn't work. I read [here](https://medium.com/nuxt/nuxt-2-is-coming-oh-yeah-212c1a9e1a67) that it is internally used by nuxt, but i don't know how to add it here.

Hope anyone has an idea where to look...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just figured it out: you have to use the `publicPath` option of the webfonts-loader package:

```
extend(config, ctx) {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /plugins\/icons\.js$/,
    use: [
      'vue-style-loader',
      'css-loader',
      { 
        loader: 'webfonts-loader',
        options: {
          publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
        },
      }
    ],
  })
}
```

The `config.output.publicPath` is `/_nuxt/`.